# Dependency Injection for factory with parameters resolved at creation time

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

Here's what I want to be able to do in my application:

```
public void BusinessLogic (IFactory workerFactory)
{
  string specificObjectType = ... // not known in advance
  IWorkerObject workerObject = workerFactory.CreateByType(specificObjectType);
  workerObject.DoActualWork();
}
```

In other words, I want an actual Factory that generates various kinds of `IWorkerObject` implementations on demand, and I want that Factory to be injectable. And ideally that Factory itself would be able to get those implementation object from the service container too:

```
public class WorkerFactory
{
  public WorkerFactory (IServiceContainer ...)
  { ... }

  public IWorker CreateByType (string type)
  {
    return ...; // a thing that can be provided by the service container
  }
}
```

The reason is that I want to be able to create (for example) a `SteelWorker` or a `CopperWorker` or an `AluminumWorker` depending on what type of metal is represented by that `specificObjectType` value. This seems like a normal Factory pattern to me, but I don't know how to make a class injectable *and* give it parameters that aren't resolved until creation time.

If this can be done with Unity, great. If I need to work around it or use another DI framework, that is okay too.

Comment: Have you considered using generics `IWorker CreateByType<T>() where T : IWorker`

Comment: The thing I have available at creation time is a string like "Steel" or "Copper" though, and the `IWorker` implementations themselves are not generic in nature; i.e., the `SteelWorker` class is very different from the `CopperWorker` class.

So that would at best be pushing the problem down to resolving the `T`, which is the problem I already have.

Comment: Why would you want this?

Answer (score 0):

You could inject an IServiceScopeFactory into the IFactory

```
using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    if(criteriaA)
    {
        return scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<WorkerA>();
    }
}
```